# How to join two different jarvis log event

Tags: kql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S76kJ.png)

I'am writing KQL on Filtering conditions,I want join two event datas.My KQL like this:

```
let table1=source
|where LogName == "FraudServiceRequest"
| project d_name=LogName,PreciseTimeStamp,ConnectionID,End=substring(TimeStamp,13,20);

let table2=source
| where LogName == "ProxyReceivedRequest"
| project ConnectionID,Start=substring(TimeStamp,13,20);

table1
| join (table2)
    on $left.ConnectionID == $right.ConnectionID
|project ConnectionID,m_Ans=(toreal(End)-toreal(Start))/1000.0
```

But there no one record response.
Can you help me,Thanks very very much.

Comment: It might be that there are no matching records on both sides of the join.
Also, your Start/End calculations that pass TimeStamp via substring look strange and might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Alexander,The TimeStamp is a string like "20200814080500200802",I tried  both sides of the join and it's no problem.

Comment: I want to know can we use join on two event.

Comment: You should be able to run the join. Please check that ConnectionID is appears on both sides of the join (in table1, table2)

Comment: ConnectionID is existed on both sides of the join. The code can run on client query. The detail :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483951/join-across-two-different-event

Comment: Seems your question is not about KQL (which works) - but about a specific experience UX. Since this question and the referenced questions are duplicate - I would recommend deleting one (e.g. this one).